# WPF: Is ListBox or Panel responsible for mouse wheel navigation?

Tags: wpf, listbox, navigation, mouse, panel

I have a custom ListBox which uses a custom Panel as ItemsHost. I want to have control over mouse wheel input, so that turning the wheel changes the single selected item.

I believe that the best method to do so is to handle the OnPreviewMouseWheel event (although this is only have what I want since it doesn't provide horizontal wheel data).

Now the big question: Is there a best practice where to handle OnPreviewMouseWheel? In ListBox (which by default doesn't have a clue about the arrangement of the Panel's child elements) or in Panel (which by default doesn't have a clue about the "IsSelected" property of it's child elements)?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should do this from the `ListBox`.  `ListBox` inherits from [Selector](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.selector.aspx) which handles everything to do with selection.

The mousewheel selection behavior could apply with any kind of `Panel` (it might even be a good idea to implement it using a standard `ListBox` first), and you might want to use the `Panel` somewhere outside of a `ListBox` where the selection logic would make no sense.

Answer (score 0):

It should be done from the ListBox as only it knows about what item is currently selected. The panel doesn't want or need to know if it selected or not.

I would recommend implementing this as an attached behavior so you can re-use the functionality multiple times.

To do this:
- create a new class (maybe called ListBoxSelector) with an attached property called MouseWheelChangesSelection (true/false).
- add a PropertyNotifyChangedEvent and when the property is changed register an event listener for the PreviewMouseWheel / MouseWheel events.

You could change the currently selected item by either:
- incrementing the selected index; or
- using the collection view source's move prev/next